# Inserting Data into MySQL table using HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, forms

I am currently trying to insert rows into a MySQL database, and most of the code is there but I'm having a few issues I can't diagnose. I know the database connection is good, and every time the submit button is pressed it runs the correct php script. The issue I'm having is that it always adds 2 records to the database table and fails to carry though any of the form data (it inserts two completely blank rows.)

Here's the code for the form (with a little extra code for the wordpress page)

```
  <div class="main-container">
<div class="content-area">
    <div class="middle-align">
        <div class="site-main" id="sitefull">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
            <div>
                <form method="POST" name="cutting tool" action="add-tool-script.php">
                    <table style="width:auto;">
                        <tr>
                            <th width="50%"><h2><ul>Tool Information</ul></h2><br></th>
                            <th width="50%"><ul><h2>Storage Information</h2></ul><br></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <h3>Tooling Name</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="e.g. ShearHog"><br><br>

                                <h3>Tooling Type</h3><br>
                                <select name="type">
                                    <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                                    <option value="Ballnose Endmill">Ballnose Endmill</option>
                                    <option value="Bullnose Endmill">Bullnose Endmill</option>
                                    <option value="Boring Bar">Boring Bar</option>
                                    <option value="Brush">Brush</option>
                                    <option value="Burnishing">Burnishing</option>
                                    <option value="Chamfer Mill">Chamfer Mill</option>
                                    <option value="Countersink">Countersink</option>
                                    <option value="Drill">Drill</option>
                                    <option value="Drill/Mill">Drill/Mill</option>
                                    <option value="Engraver">Engraver</option>
                                    <option value="Face Mill">Face Mill</option>
                                    <option value="Flat Endmill">Flat Endmill</option>
                                    <option value="High Feed Mill">High Feed Mill</option>
                                    <option value="Reamer">Reamer</option>
                                    <option value="Slitting Saw">Slitting Saw</option>
                                    <option value="Spot Drill">Spot Drill</option>
                                    <option value="Tap">Tap</option>
                                    <option value="Threadmill">Threadmill</option>
                                    <option value="Woodruff">Woodruff</option>
                                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                </select><br><br>

                                <h3>Tooling Brand</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="brand" placeholder="e.g. Lakeshore Carbide"><br><br>

                                <h3>Part Number</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="part_number" placeholder="e.g. 360014X"><br><br>

                                <h3>Price</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="e.g. 24.95"><br><br>

                                <h3>Overall Length</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="oal" placeholder="e.g. 2.5"><br><br>

                                <h3>Tooling Material</h3><br>
                                <select name="material">
                                    <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                                    <option value="Carbide">Carbide</option>
                                    <option value="Ceramic">Ceramic</option>
                                    <option value="Diamond">Diamond</option>
                                    <option value="HSS">HSS</option>
                                    <option value="Powdered Metal">Powdered Metal</option>
                                </select><br><br>

                                <h3>Cutting Diameter</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="cutting_diam" placeholder="e.g. 0.250"><br><br>

                                <h3>Shank Diameter</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="shank_diam" placeholder="e.g. .250"><br><br>

                                <h3>Number of Flutes</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="flutes" placeholder="e.g. 3"><br><br>

                                <h3>Length of Cut (Flute Length)</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="loc" placeholder="e.g. .750"><br><br>

                                <h3>Corner Radius</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="corner_rad" placeholder="e.g. .004"><br><br>
                            </td>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <h3>Quantity in Stock</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="e.g. 37"><br><br>

                                <h3>Minimum Trigger Quantity</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="trigger_qty" placeholder="e.g. 4"><br><br>

                                <h3>Reorder Link</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="reorder_link" placeholder="e.g. example.com"><br><br>

                                <h3>Toolbox Number</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="toolbox_no" placeholder="e.g. 1"><br><br>

                                <h3>Drawer Number</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="drawer_no" placeholder="e.g. 1"><br><br>

                                <h3>Bin Number</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="bin_no" placeholder="e.g. 1"><br><br>

                                <h3>Product</h3><br>
                                <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="e.g. Widget #2"><br><br>

                                <input type="submit" value="Add to Tool Crib" name="submitbutton" action="submit"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </form>
            </div>
                <?php
                //If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                    comments_template();
                ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here's the code for the php script to add form data to the database:

```
   //MySQL Database
    $servername = "url.com";
    $username = "user_login";
    $password = "user_password";
    $datab = "database_name";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $datab);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$brand = $_REQUEST['brand'];
$part_number = $_REQUEST['part_number'];
$price = $_REQUEST['price'];
$oal = $_REQUEST['oal'];
$material = $_REQUEST['material'];
$cutting_diam = $_REQUEST['cutting_diam'];
$shank_diam = $_REQUEST['shank_diam'];
$flutes = $_REQUEST['flutes'];
$loc = $_REQUEST['loc'];
$corner_rad = $_REQUEST['corner_rad'];
$qty = $_REQUEST['qty'];
$trigger_qty = $_REQUEST['trigger_qty'];
$reorder_link = $_REQUEST['reorder_link'];
$toolbox_no = $_REQUEST['toolbox_no'];
$drawer_no = $_REQUEST['drawer_no'];
$bin_no = $_REQUEST['bin_no'];
$product = $_REQUEST['product'];
$username = $user_login;

$sql = "INSERT INTO `cutting tools` (`name`, `type`, `brand`, `part_number`, `reorder_link`, `oal`, `price`, `material`, `cutting_diam`, `shank_diam`, `flutes`, `loc`, `corner_rad`, `qty`, `trigger_qty`, `user`, `drawer_no`, `bin_no`, `toolbox_no`) 
        VALUES ('$name', '$type', '$brand', '$part_number', '$reorder_link', '$oal', '$price', '$material', '$cutting_diam', '$shank_diam', '$flutes', '$loc', '$corner_rad', '$qty', '$trigger_qty', '$username', '$drawer_no', '$bin_no', '$toolbox_no')";


if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "Record added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Also I know my database is vulnerable to injection, that was a change I planned on making once the form was up and running.

Comment: If it's inserting blank rows and echo'ing "Record added successfully.", then my first check would be to see if there's anything in `$_REQUEST`. What does `var_dump($_REQUEST);` output when you submit the form? (sidenote: you almost never want to use `$_REQUEST` since it's a mix of query parameters, posted form values and cookie values and it depends on server configuration which one your script actually receives. In this case, prefer using `$_POST` instead)

Answer (score 1):

Use WordPress to your advantage.  Instead of defining your own connection, use global $wpdb, and then use the insert command.

```
global $wpdb;

$success = $wpdb->insert('tbl_name', array(<br>
   'field1_name' => $_REQUEST['field1'],<br>
   'field2_name' => $_REQUEST['field2'],<br>
));<br>
if($success){<br>
   echo "Inserted correctly";<br>
} else {<br>
   echo "Something went awry!";<br>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a prepared statement, a more secure way of creating a MYSQL record in your table.

```
<?php    
//MySQL Database
$servername = "url.com";
$username = "user_login";
$password = "user_password";
$datab = "database_name";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $datab);
global $con;

// Post form data
$name = $_POST['name'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$part_number = $_POST['part_number'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$oal = $_POST['oal'];
$material = $_POST['material'];
$cutting_diam = $_POST['cutting_diam'];
$shank_diam = $_POST['shank_diam'];
$flutes = $_POST['flutes'];
$loc = $_POST['loc'];
$corner_rad = $_POST['corner_rad'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$trigger_qty = $_POST['trigger_qty'];
$reorder_link = $_POST['reorder_link'];
$toolbox_no = $_POST['toolbox_no'];
$drawer_no = $_POST['drawer_no'];
$bin_no = $_POST['bin_no'];
$product = $_POST['product'];

// Prepared statement
$insert = mysqli_prepare($con, "insert into cutting tools (name,type,brand,part_number,reorder_link,oal,price,material,cutting_diam,shank_diam,flutes,loc,corner_rad,qty,trigger_qty,user,drawer_no,bin_no,toolbox_no) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert, "sssssssssssssssssss", $name,$type,$brand,$part_number,$reorder_link,$oal,$price,$material,$cutting_diam,$shank_diam,$flutes,$loc,$corner_rad,$qty,$trigger_qty,$product,$drawer_no,$bin_no,$toolbox_no);
mysqli_stmt_execute($insert);

if ($insert) { echo "success"; mysqli_close($con); } else { echo "error"; mysqli_close($con); }
?>
```

Pay close attention to the order of your columns and the data you are submitting to those columns. I have edited this post because your order was incorrect in several places.

**The column names and the data variables being uploaded to them have to be in the exact same order if you want data created correctly.**

By the way the variable $product does not seem to match the column name of user, you may want to check this.